# My container won't go in its parent container

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get the black box to go into the blue box.
As far as I know, the black box is in the same container as the red box; therefore the black box is suppose to be in the blue box.

http://codepen.io/VK72m/pen/yMJLRZ

```css
/* Containers */

main.container {
  height: 40em;
  width: 70%;
  top: 5em;
  background-color: orange;
}

section.bluebox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

figure.redbox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

summary.blackbox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 62%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Styles */

summary.blackbox p {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section class="bluebox">
    <figure class="redbox">
      <p> FIGURE </p>
    </figure>
    <summary class="blackbox">
      <p> SUMMARY </p>
    </summary>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You should add `float: left` to `section.redbox`

Comment: Get rid of the height on bluebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the current [`HTML Standard`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-figure-element) on `<figure>` element:

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained (like a complete sentence) and is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document.

which is intepreted by most browsers and, more importantly, by the widely used ones as:

```
figure { 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Having a display of `block` will make it occupy `100%` of width and push every other *"block level item"*, such as `<summary>` on a new line. Below.

There are multiple ways you can achieve the desired result. However, doing it with the least amount of code would be

```
figure {float: left}
```

```css
main.container {
  height: 40em;
  width: 70%;
  top: 5em;
  background-color: orange;
}

section.bluebox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

figure.redbox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

summary.blackbox {
  height: 10em;
  width: 62%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Styles */

summary.blackbox p {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {float: left;}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section class="bluebox">
    <figure class="redbox">
      <p> FIGURE </p>
    </figure>
    <summary class="blackbox">
      <p> SUMMARY </p>
    </summary>
  </section>
</main>
```

---

If you wanted to have the red and black boxes fill the blue one, I personally recommend flexbox, but it's strictly a matter of personal preference (there are multiple other ways to achieve it):

```css
section { 
  display: flex;
}
section > figure, section > summary {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.bluebox {
  min-height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.redbox {
  width: 24%;
  max-width: 24%;
  background-color: red;
}

.blackbox {
  background-color: black;
}
figure, summary, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

/* Styles */

.blackbox p {
  color: white;
}

section { 
  display: flex;
}
section > figure, 
section > summary {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <section class="bluebox">
    <figure class="redbox">
      <p> FIGURE </p>
    </figure>
    <summary class="blackbox">
      <p> SUMMARY </p>
    </summary>
  </section>
</main>
```

In this last example, I took the liberty to interpret your intentions and re-code your `CSS` into what I believe to be best practices, making as few assumptions as possible.
Please note it's not production ready, it should be prefixed before deploying.

Comment: I thought semantic tags were the same as div tags. I just started using semantic tags because it was said to be good for SEO.

Comment: It is indeed. But I think you should clearly specify their `display` property so they display as you like. You're not bound to use any defaults. If my answer doesn't help you achieve your desired visual result, please reformulate your question so it is clear what you want to achieve and I will updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block elements, so they naturally go to their own line. You can apply float:left; to both the red and black box to fit inside the blue box.

Comment: There is no `<div>` in that example, Ben.

Comment: My mistake. Those are still blocks elements, though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements. And yeah, it can just be applied to red, but I figured "Figure" + "Summary" would be weird with word wrap, which will happen with just one element floating.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I came the to the conclusion that only the first child element of the parent will go in the parent element. Hence, the redbox was the first child of the bluebox, therefore it went in.

Comment: Oh, were you trying to have the blue box extend in height, rather than have red and black side-by-side? In that case, you shouldn't float anything and remove the height of the blue box.

Comment: No you were correct. I wanted to have the red box and the black box side by side.